# create an account on Parse

Tags: github, parse-platform

I wanted to create an account on the platform Parse but I receive a message saying that Parse no longer exists .. They changed their web address ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gl25.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,parse services are no longer available ,consider using firebase or something along that lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really create an account, but you can still use their service as it is open sourced now. [Parse](http://parseplatform.org)

Answer (score 0):

So while Parse is no longer available as a service from the company you can still set up your own parse server and run it yourself. It is open source now. You can use heroku and github has great documentation on this. The link is below.

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server